# How can I solve this .obj to .icn conversion problem?

Tags: export, obj

I'm trying to create `.icn` models for homebrew PS2 save icons. Is there a way to export `.icn` files directly? or How do I approach this problem?

1. I prepare the simplest model I could in blender v2.92
2. Then I create a UV map and use a 128x128 px `.tga` file as a texture
   image
3. Then I export finished model as `.obj`
4. Blender puts out a `.obj` and a `.mtl` file but there's no extra
   texture file(I also don't have the copy texture file checkbox which
   was shown in some of the videos online.)
5. When I open the `.obj` file(that I exported) in Win 10 3D viewer, it
   shows the model fine with the texture and everything.
6. But then I convert the `.obj` model to a `.icn` model using some
   homebrew tool and when I try to create the actual `icon.sys` file with the model; it shows the wireframe and/or a badly(full of holes) textured model.

Although this homebrew tool works with some other `.obj` files, It doesn't seem to work with what blender puts out.

So is there a way to export `.icn` files directly with blender? or how do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

after trying everything for days I asked that question and to my chance I reached a solution from somewhere else.

so the solution was to create triangle's instead of quads for the faces and that's it. nothing else is needed.